# retrieve bean value using jstl

Tags: jstl

```
 public class CCDocumentHeaderBean
  {
    boolean TransportRequested;
public void setTransportRequested(boolean newTransportRequested) {
        TransportRequested = newTransportRequested;
    }
public boolean isTransportRequested() {
        return TransportRequested;
    }   

}
CCDocumentHeaderBean lDocHeaderBean = new CCDocumentHeaderBean();
 lDocHeaderBean = (CCDocumentHeaderBean)session.getValue("CustomHeaderValue");

<input type="checkbox" name="chkSelectNo"     
                            <c:if test="${lDocHeaderBean.TransportRequested== false}">
                         checked 
                        </c:if> 
        onClick = "javascript:onSelectNo();">
```

in this code i have CCDocumentHeaderBean class i store this TransportRequest property when the page gets loaded. i want to retrieve the value in checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
<c:if test="${lDocHeaderBean.TransportRequested== false}">
    checked 
</c:if>
```

Your coding convention is bad. Property names ought start with lowercase. Fix it accordingly.

```
<c:if test="${not lDocHeaderBean.transportRequested}">
    checked 
</c:if>
```

Note that it doesn't make sense to compare a boolean property value to a boolean in order to get a boolean outcome. Just return the boolean property value outright. If you want to inverse it, just use the `!` or `not` operator, as demonstrated above.